# Propriedade height do jQuery e do JavaScript, qual diferença?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual a diferença entre `$(window).height()` do jQuery para o `screen.height` do JavaScript ?
Usando eles percebo resultados diferentes...

E qual o similar ao `screen.height` no jQuery ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As duas funções tratam de aspectos diferentes:

- `screen.height` = altura baseada na resolução do monitor
- `$(window).height()` = altura da **janela** do browser

O objeto `screen` do JavaScript remete a resolução da tela do usuário, de forma que o tamanho da janela do navegador não interfere nos seus valores. Já o objeto `$(window)` usado pelo jQuery trata justamente da janela do navegador, sendo que `$(window).height()` é equivalente à função `window.innerHeight` em JavaScript puro.

O objeto `screen` não é tratado pelo jQuery. Mas como o @Jader disse na resposta dele, jQuery nada mais é do que JavaScript, ou seja, você pode utilizar `screen.height` com seu código jQuery sem problemas.

Answer (score 6):

No jquery o `$(window).height()` é o tamanho da janela de exibição (viewport), já `screen.height` é o tamanho total da tela do usuário.

Tenha em mente que jquery é javascript, e você pode usar `screen.height` nele sem nenhum problema, se o caso for obter o tamanho da tela...